# SQLITE from a bash script: how to deal with bash variables?

Tags: sql, bash, sqlite

I have the following bash script that executes an sql query

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

FILE=$2
sqlite3 $1 <<'END_SQL'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
.headers on                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
.mode csv                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
.output $FILE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
select * from results;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
.output stdout                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
END_SQL
```

So, I want the results to be sent to the file I pass with $2. However, it prints the results to a file named $FILE. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

To perform variable expansion, don't quote the `END_SQL`.

But be sure the variable is checked against SQL injection, e.g.

```bash
# Don't run this on the real database, it deletes all the data!
FILE='output.txt
DROP TABLE results;'
sqlite3 $1 <<END_SQL
.headers on
.mode csv
.output $FILE
select * from results; -- Error: no such table
END_SQL
```